Firebase project deploying to old deleted project
I am trying to deploy a new firebase project (fit-prototype-v0 below), but it keeps deploying to an old project (fit-test-for-readme). I deleted the old project, and now get the error below. I'm guessing I accidentally copied over an old name somewhere, but I'm not sure where to look. How can I resolve this?
(base) 16:24:58 ~/Dropbox/FIT/FIT-Prototype-v0
⠠⠵ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'fit-test-for-readme'...

i  deploying storage, firestore, hosting
i  storage: ensuring required API firebasestorage.googleapis.com is enabled...

Error: HTTP Error: 403, Project '995371384680' not found or permission denied.
Help Token: AaUeqG6BwOkJwbHbgwPpD3_9EFhQseNbO5zwK9lR5uMB1LbU16Ep8bez13kiKcwi9uQPp30GIkqEXdSvhRkt0i-57ynC8XRtgwCtmtjl2FGpJP3w


The Firebase CLI uses the contents of the file ".firebaserc" in the current directory to determine the name of the project to deploy to.  For example:
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "NAME-OF-PROJECT"
  }
}

If it can't find this file in the current directory, it will work its way up parent directories to find one.  You almost certainly still have one of these files lying around, which is telling the CLI to deploy to that project.  You need to delete or modify that file to help it deal with the new project.
See the Firebase CLI reference, and look for occrrences of ".firebaserc" to see how it's used in more detail.

It looks like you can just use firebase use [new project]
